# Order by nested object in RethinkDB using Go driver

Tags: go, rethinkdb

How is it possible using Go driver fetch data from RethinkDB in order by of nested object?

So let's imagine I have such json in my table:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "date": "2001-01-15",
        "time": {
            "begin": "09:00",
            "end": "10:30"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "date": "2001-01-16",
        "time": {
            "begin": "08:30",
            "end": "10:30"
        }
    }
]
```

Go model is:

```
type MyTime struct {
    Begin time.Time `json:"begin"`
    End   time.Time `json:"end"`
}

type Something struct {
    Id      string `json:"id"`
    Date    time.Time `json:"date"`
    Time    MyTime `json:"time"`
}
```

Example how it is possible to order by id:

```
var result []Something
db.Table("someTable").OrderBy("id").Run(session).All(&result)
```

I tried to order by beginning of time like this (thinking that the approach is the same as in ArangoDB, but apparently it is not):

```
 var result []Something
 db.Table("someTable").OrderBy("time.begin").Run(session).All(&result)
```

I saw an example on the official site how it works by using native javascript driver

> ```
> Example: Use nested field syntax to sort on fields from subdocuments. (You can also 
> create indexes on nested fields using this syntax with indexCreate.)
>
> r.table('user').orderBy(r.row('group')('id')).run(conn, callback)
> ```

But it is not really clear how to transform it to Go.

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function, something like this:

```
db.Table("someTable").OrderBy(func(row Term) Term {
    return row.Field("time").Field("begin")
}).Run(session).All(&result)
```

Comment: It's defined by the driver: https://github.com/dancannon/gorethink/blob/e590ff2fbe7286788da60f90e6b2bfced91dca66/query.go#L16

Comment: Thanks, it works! I just started working with rethinkgo driver, that's why I didn't find it :) But there was no problem for me to migrate to another one